# Python. Building a list of joined objects based on a single or multiple attributes

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement JOIN function for a list of objects.
I have a list of objects like that:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.RegionId
        self.ItemId
        self.Price
```

Based on that list I'd like to build a joined object which is joining prices for two given regions based on ItemId. The result object shall be like this:

```
class ItemInRegions(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ItemId
        self.PriceInRegion1
        self.PriceInRegion2
```

I've implemented a FOR loop but it takes really long two iterate through every individual object in the list.

I'm sure Python should have a quick and effective way to join to identical lists of objects. Effectively I'm looking for a Python solution which simulates INNER JOIN SQL query:

```
SELECT i1.id, i1.Price,i2.Price 
FROM ItemList i1
INNER JOIN ItemList i2 on i1.ItemId=i2.ItemId and i1.Region='Region1' and i2.Region='Region2'
```

where ItemList represents list of objects Item

Comment: would you consider your data tabular and fairly flat? If it's suitable you should consider using `pandas` and it will easily allow you to join different rows in your dataframe. see https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_join_merge_dataframe/

Comment: Python is a programming language, not a relational database, so trying to model your domain as a relational model will not work. Either use a relational database and an ORM (peewee comes to mind...) or use proper OO modeling.

Comment: Though I have never used pandas it seems like that might be a good tool for what you are trying to do. A database is _really_ the right tool for this as they are designed to do these types of things. If you need to do it in python and don't need the flexibility of a database (i.e. you really just want to do this one thing) Then I recommend something along the lines of building a dictionary where the key is the ItemId as the objects are created, and the value is a list of the objects with that ItemId.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this more of an architecture problem.

An `Item` should contain a `Region` which should be a object also. that way you could retrieve prices based on that region.

Comment: Item object contains RegionId. I can extract price for each Item and Regions but using FOR loop seems to be inefctive way of doing so.

Comment: It is ineffective in the way that you're not using the right tool in order to achieve what you want. I thought that you wanted to have items with related region which also had prices related to them, hence my proposition. Maybe the truth is you're to model a database use-case to OOP which is not always optimal.